# BCP/xp_cmdshell access denied - but only when running procedure from outside the server

Tags: sql-server, kerberos, bcp

I've been attempting to run some of my team's database deployment code to a SQL 2014 server on a Windows 7 test box. Part of this code is a procedure that pulls in data from a file using BCP from a file share on another server.

When I remote desktop onto the server and run the procedure through SQL management studio the procedure is successful. However when I run the procedure from SQL management studio on any other machine (or via our deployment tool which connects via ADO) I get:

Cannot bulk load because the file "\... ..." could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.).

I've checked the 'show advanced options' and 'xp_cmdshell' settings and like I say, it DOES work. But only when I am logged into the server, not other machines.

Does anybody know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Upon both servers, run XP_CMDSHELL 'WHOAMI' and note the results.
2. Logon as the account or accounts that were identified by 1, upon both servers.
3. Use the same xp_cmdshell string from a command prompt (cmd.exe), upon both servers.
4. Talk to your AD folks about the results.